# How to fetch an object from array of dictionaries in ios

Tags: ios7

I have an array of dictionaries with multiple keys and objects of different types. I want to fetch only one of the object and compare with the other object. I have been trying with for each loop but not bee able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
```

then iterate the keys in the dictionary

```
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
```

then extract the value for the key:

```
id obj = dict[key];
```

Then test the object type and compare with the other object:

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSString *stringObj = (NSString *)obj;
    if ([stringObj isEqualToString:otherObj]) {
        NSLog(@"Object equals dictionary entry %@", key);
    }
} else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    NSNumber *numberObj = (NSNumber *)obj;
    if ([numberObj isEqual:otherObj]) {
        NSLog(@"Object equals dictionary entry %@", key);
    }
} else // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

first get the dictionary from array

```
NSDictionary *dict=[yourarray objectAtIndex:index];
```

then get the object from dictionary

```
NSString *yourValue=[dict objectForKey:@"Your KeyValue"];
```

In case of for each loop

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in yourArray) {
NSString *yourValue=[dict objectForKey:@"Your KeyValue"];
NSLog(@"%@",yourValue);
}
```

Comment: please put some explanation to your posted answer.